# Border-collapse for lists?

Tags: css, border, html-lists

Is there a border-collapse:collapse alternative for lists, where the li's are displayed as blocks with a border of 1px solid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the top border on all but the first list item by adding:

```
li:not(:first-child) {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/3h8bm/

IE8 and IE7 don't support `:not`. However, they do support `:first-child`, so a workaround is easy:

```
li {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-top: 0;
}
li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/3h8bm/4/

IE6 doesn't support either of those, so if you're worried about that browser, you'll have to add a custom class (say, `.first-child`) to the first element directly.